# Solution Configurations drop down list in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. My problem is I'm not getting the solution configurations drop down list.I tried a lot but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Where? On the toolbar? Have you enabled and diasabled the appropriate tool bar?

Comment: Yes on the toolbar.It belongs to the standard toolbar.I tried to customize the standard toolbar, but i couldn't add that.

Comment: Can you right click on the Solution and go to properties and see the different configs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx

Comment: Actually i need to change the build configuration from debug mode to release mode.I changed the mode as mentioned in the msdn page.But during building it is still in the debug mode,not in the release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Tools menu, click Settings, and then click Expert Settings.

The Solution Configuration list box appears in the Standard toolbar. Click Debug or Release.

If still not visible, [check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928362%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)